# Angular.js - ng-disabled on checkbox and still submit a valid form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I'm using angular.js and trying to verify the form before actually submitting it. This is my HTML so far:

```
<form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="branch.phone_number" name="uPhone" required="" />
                <br />
                <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.uPhone.$touched">
                    <div ng-show="form.uPhone.$error.required">Insert phone number!</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="branch.approved" ng-checked="branch.approved === 1" required="" ng-disabled="checkUser()" />
            </td>
        <tr/>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <input type="button" ng-click="reset()" value="Reset" />
            </td>
        <tr/>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <input type="submit" ng-click="form.$valid && save()" value="Save" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And this is my `checkUser` function:

```
    $scope.checkUser = function() {
        return (user.get().is_admin === 1) ? false : true;
    };
```

Basically, if `ng-model="branch.approved"` is not truthy, the form won't allow to submit it. If I delete the ng-disabled attribute, the form submits.

What's going on and how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Is it perhaps because the checkbox input is `required`?

Comment: oh boy, so trivial. thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Good job, you should write it as an actual answer @Starscream1984!

Comment: Nice, glad it worked for you, have added an actual answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checkbox is `required` - when the control is disabled, it is not setting any value.

Remove the `required=""` attribute from `input type="checkbox"` and it should work as you expect

Answer (score 0):

try this:

use `ng-disabled="user.is_admin"` then use ng-change on checkbox like this `ng-change="checkUser()"`

change the function to

```
$scope.checkUser = function() {
    $scope.user = user.get();
};
```

i guess the user admin state can change during the form life... otherwise u don't need the change event just use `ng-disabled="user.is_admin"` and initialize the user object inside the controller